# Apollo/GraphQL/React, How to query for data in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo

In one of my React components, I have an array that includes a number of IDs as Strings. I want to query each ID in the array and return an array of its associated objects within my MongoDB database. However, this only happens conditionally, so I wanted to use useLazyQuery instead of useQuery.

I tried to accomplish it via mapping, but it seems I had an issue with using useLazyQuery. Here's the issue:

```
const [queryId, {loading, data}] = useLazyQuery[QUERY_ID];

if (queryForIds) {
    // Using just the first ID
   (queryId({variables: {id: idList[0]}}));
   console.log(data);
}
```

This results in an infinite loop of nothing being printed (maybe my resolver returns nothing but regardless I get an infinite loop that crashes my site). I am most likely misusing useLazyQuery but I'm unsure of how.

Originally my idea was to do this:

```
const [queryId, {loading, data}] = useLazyQuery[QUERY_ID];

if (queryForIds) {
    // Using just the first ID
   idList.map((id) => (queryId({variables: {id: idList[0]}}))).data);
}
```

But I'm also unsure if that works either. How can I resolve either issue?

Comment: you can try to use a `new Promise`, resolve in `onCompleted`, `Promise.all`/ etc. ... but easier is to implement some query/resolver taking an array of ids [and returning an array of objects]

Comment: I ended up handling it in the resolver, thank you.

Comment: @jon can you post an example?